# Not able to update middle fragment in View Pager.

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I've been working on a TAB layout with 3 tabs.

My problem is
I'm unable to update,refresh 2nd tab swiping between the pages.

As per my debugging
I swipe from tab one to second, the third is being called at getItem(int position), similarly fragment one is being called swiping from third tab to second.

The default **getOffscreenPageLimit** of viewpager is **1**. I couldn't even set it to zero count.

At getItem, position is 1 at the very beginning but as soon as I swipe page, 
it only calls position 0 and 2. 
1 is never called.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}
```

This is my ViewPagerSetUp

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new 
ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new InvitedFragment(), "Invited");
    adapter.addFragment(new InterestedFragment(), "Interested");
    adapter.addFragment(new AttendingFragment(), "Attending");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is my ViewPager

```
 class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    public void refreshFragment(int position) {
        mFragmentList.get(position).onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

addOnPageChangeListener was one option but I couldn't refresh it using pageChangelistener too.

How can I cure offscreenpagelimit ? 
How can I refresh every tab on every page swipe?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

Override the below method in fragment.It call when fragment is visible

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        //do your Stuffs
    }
}
```

Comment: As setUserVisibleHint is executed at very beginning, I had to add **isResumed** too. 

Thanks Pradeep for suggestion. 

if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {
        //do your Stuffs
}

Comment: `if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed())` you save my day, can you edit your answer @PradeepGupta

Answer (score 1):

add this in your activity

```
  viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

in your adapter add this,

```
 @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
       return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add View Pager into tabLayout if you not added then try this code:

```
 tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

also you are calling Parent Fragment(super) onResume Method in refreshFragment method you have to call SubFragment onResume method :

```
    mInvitedFragment.onResume();
    mInterestedFragment.onResume();
    mAttendingFragment.onResume();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method for refresh second fragment.Put this method in the fragment.

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
        if (visible) {
            //   load data here
        }else {
            // fragment is no longer visible
        }
    }
```